# Find CPU usage of single process

Tags: macos, htop

Hi I'm trying to find the number of cores in use by a single proces using htop.

> htop -p processid

I've tried the above commando and this shows the single process but gives the cpu usage of all processes. Is there a way to show a single process and only show the cpu usage of that single process?